# IF statement in batch file not working properly

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

```
@ECHO OFF
PAUSE 
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\NexphaseV6\ECF" (
    ECHO Directory exists! 
    PAUSE
) ELSE (
    MKDIR "C:\Program Files\NexphaseV6\ECF" 
    ECHO Directory made!
)
PAUSE
```

When I run the above batch file I always get the opposite results of what I expect.

So if the directory does exist, it says "Directory Made!", and if it doesn't exist, it says "Directory Exists!"

It's basically the wrong way round - Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file looks fine to me and works here (as long as you have directory creation rights in *Program Files* of course, so you might want to run it from an elevated (admin) command prompt).

One tip is to modify the directory existence test slightly. Instead of:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\NexphaseV6\ECF"
```

you should use:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\NexphaseV6\ECF\"
```

Note the trailing backslash. This ensures that if there's a file by that same name then the test won't return True.

Comment: Not too sure how I got it working as I was already running as admin although it works now, thanks!